# How to suppress intellij IDEA error in editor when using Binding.scala macro annotation?

Tags: scala, dom, scala.js, web-frontend, binding.scala

Despite it compiles and runs in sbt console.
Intellij complains that I should have Binding[Node] instead of Elem in editor.

```
@dom def renderDiv: Binding[Div] = <div>...</div>
```

From intellij IDEA's perspective, this method returns a `Elem` which is a subtype of `scala.xml.Node`,
but when rendering:

```
dom.render(document.getElementById("root"),renderDiv)
```

it requires a `org.scalajs.dom.raw.Node`.

Is there any workaround to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could put an implicit conversion def in scope:

```
package object xxx {
  implicit def makeIntellijHappy[T<:org.scalajs.dom.raw.Node](x: scala.xml.Node): Binding[T] =
    throw new AssertionError("This should never execute.")
}
```

define method above in the package object, thus it covers the whole package. This method will never be executed, actually.