# How to make Scala Presentation Compiler happy with Binding.scala?

Tags: scala, ensime, binding.scala

I use ENSIME to deal with Scala code, and ENSIME uses official Presentation Compiler. For all Binding.scala examples I looked at `@dom` functions result in "all is red" decoration (that is false positive error detection) for DOM fragments. Say this one example https://github.com/Atry/Binding.scala-sample results in "all is red" starting from the first `div` of the `table` definition.

I guess Eclipse users are also affected by the issue as far as Eclipse uses PC also.

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: I don't know if this workaround is applicable:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617401/how-to-suppress-intellij-idea-error-in-editor-when-using-binding-scala-macro-ann

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't. Have tried that first.

Answer (score 1):

use `addEnsimeCompilerPlugin` in addition to `addCompilerPlugin`. This will be addressed by https://github.com/ensime/ensime-server/issues/1152

Comment: Did you mean `addEnsimeCompilerPlugin` for the macro paradise plugin?